# Data won't show up in table but does in console.log

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, api

My data does show up in the console.log but not actually into the table, what am I doing wrong here?

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/api/metatrader", function(data){ console.log(data.result)

var table = document.getElementById('historyTable')

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  var row = `<tr>
                <td>${data.result[i].order}</td>
                <td>${data.result[i].symbol}</td>
                <td>${data.result[i].size}</td>
                <td>${data.result[i].profit}</td>
                <td>${data.result[i].tp}</td>
                <td>${data.result[i].sl}</td>
            </tr>`
  table.innerHTML += row

}

});
```

Comment: Is historyTable the exact id? Do you get errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to iterate over data.result, so try this instead:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.result.length; i++){
```

And to insert rows, follow the instruction from this exampe: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the correct answer!